# OData Metadata initial loading of metadata failed SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I've configured my destination on "**SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit**" and set my model in manifest.js and in neo-app.js. I've followed the instruction as giving in this URL [OData Remote Model configuration](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109.html)

I'm getting Error.

[ODataMetadata] initial loading of metadata failed - "

the URL of My Service is ..

https://xxxx.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/xxx/xxx/xxx.xsodata/DLES_CONTENT.

Simple XML of top 1 element is as which I use to access on browser via my above url .

```
    <feedxmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"xml:base="https://xxx.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com:443/xxx/xxx/xxx.xsodata/">
<titletype="text">xxx</title>
<id>
https://xxx.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com:443/xxx/xxx/xxx.xsodata/xxx
</id>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<linkrel="self"title="xxx"href="xxx"/><entry>
<id>
https://xxx.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com:443/xxx/xxx/xxx.xsodata/xxx('225671794047739171')
</id>
<titletype="text"/><author>
<name/>
</author>
<linkrel="self"title="xxx"href="xxx('225671794047739171')"/>
<categoryterm="xxx.services.xxx.DLES_CONTENTType"scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/><contenttype="application/xml"><m:properties>
<d:IDm:type="Edm.String">225671794047739171</d:ID>
<d:YEAR_MONTHm:type="Edm.String">2016-10</d:YEAR_MONTH>
<d:YEAR_QUARTERm:type="Edm.String">2016-Q4</d:YEAR_QUARTER>
<d:USER_COUNTRY_CODEm:type="Edm.String">AE</d:USER_COUNTRY_CODE>
<d:USER_COUNTRY_TEXTm:type="Edm.String">United Arab Em.</d:USER_COUNTRY_TEXT>
<d:USER_REGIONm:type="Edm.String">EMEA</d:USER_REGION>
<d:ITEM_IDm:type="Edm.String">s4h01e_en_col95</d:ITEM_ID>
<d:ITEM_PARENTCODEm:type="Edm.String">n/a</d:ITEM_PARENTCODE>
<d:ITEM_TYPEm:type="Edm.String">E-Learning</d:ITEM_TYPE>
<d:ITEM_TITLEm:type="Edm.String">Introduction to SAP Business Suite 4 SAP HANA</d:ITEM_TITLE>
<d:SURVEY_QUESTIONm:type="Edm.String">I can apply what I have learned to my job.</d:SURVEY_QUESTION>
<d:SURVEY_DIMENSIONm:type="Edm.String">Applicability</d:SURVEY_DIMENSION>
<d:PLATFORMm:type="Edm.String">SAP Learning Hub</d:PLATFORM>
<d:RESP_VERYBADm:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:RESP_VERYBAD>
<d:RESP_BADm:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:RESP_BAD>
<d:RESP_NEUTm:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:RESP_NEUT>
<d:RESP_GOODm:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:RESP_GOOD>
<d:RESP_VERYGOODm:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:RESP_VERYGOOD>
<d:RESP_NAm:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:RESP_NA>
<d:RESP_TOTALm:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:RESP_TOTAL>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
</feed>
```

on postman when I'm pasting my URL it gives me some HTML instead of XML. 
[image: Postman Result]

Network Tab.
[image]

Network Tab  Response[image: Network Tab REsponse]

and metadata response  is  
`<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta charset='utf-8'><meta content='IE=edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'><meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'><meta content='universalui' name='uitype'><title>Log On</title><link href='/universalui/assets/favicon-6249a7207f185aeac2f455784dcefb1c.png' rel='icon' type='image' /><link href='/universalui/assets/favicon-51d035678350093f7e6da4f3a5fb320d.ico' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' /><link href='/universalui/assets/apple-touch-icon-b6b8b9f065ab8640c80a5cd2f1ef0dac.png' rel='apple-touch-icon' /><link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/universalui/assets/ids-332dd7b645f607e6aac8ae6d3e315076.css" /><meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" /><meta name="csrf-token" content="1OLGBVXXv35941jLvQaHTGXPulOaTVnwr4g9ppuRMf0qGnxumLeUX4jJjPcxb8RkWS54g0CzFnSdTOE8BgHOqg==" /><!-- third party cookies check --><!-- same origin protection check --></head><body data-pagetype='Login' data-spid='581d6aa0e4b01556e68e4b94' data-spname='padevw3c34c012.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com' style='display:none'><main class='ids-main'><div class='ids-main__content'><div aria-labelledby='ids-heading-1' class='ids-container' role='dialog'><div class='ids-login-container'><div class='ids-login-sp'><div class='ids-login-sp__sp-name'><h1 class='ids-heading-2' id='test-service-provider-name'></h1></div><div class='ids-login-sp__cta'></div></div><div class='ids-login-login ids-login-login--border'><div class='ids-login-widget'><h1 class='ids-heading-1 ids-heading-1--login' id='ids-heading-1'>Log On</h1><form id="logOnForm" autocomplete="off" role="form" class="ids-form ids-form--login" action="/saml2/idp/sso/accounts.sap.com" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="TpZSvLAizLhZupEyAsgfRcGK9yyOOnOS/N1dXSFINvGwbujXfULnmayQRQ6OoVxt/Ws1/FTEPBbOGYHHvNjJpg==" /><div class='js-global-flashes-area' id='globalMessages'></div><fieldset class='ids-fieldset ids-fieldset--login'><input type="hidden" id="hidden-xsrfProtection-field" name="xsrfProtection" value="G++/vWh+77+9Q2jvv71L77+977+9UkA2M15q77+977+977+9Ju+/vWxtBe+/vScd77+9Lu+/vToxNTAxNDkwNjkwMjg2" ><input type="hidden" name="method" value="GET"><input type="hidden" name="idpSSOEndpoint" value="https://accounts.sap.com/saml2/idp/sso/accounts.sap.com"><input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="fZFbS8QwEIX/Ssl72/SyF4ZtIWxWKKiIKyK+hTTLBtokZlJX/71pRVBEX2fOmfNxZodiHBywKZzNvXqZFIbkbRwMwrJoyOQNWIEawYhRIQQJR3ZzDWVGwXkbrLQD+Wb53yEQlQ/aGpJ0vCFPx5RVxZoWm/1qdeAHWtesZgdacM74hpZ8y0nCI5M2YnY15ByCQ8hzIaWdTMAMhcukHaGuq3xGLnPduxzR/pKQ5FF5jNkNifARAHFSncEgTIijCJHSTVoVD3QL9Qqq9TNpd/NJ6Galb53o1eulklUtaVFm2oQl/SyMyKzp1ShMP7PsFpAv13LCwW1sr+N3dtDyPWHDYC97r0RQDQl+UiS5sn4UkeOvvousWD6g+/S0SGEy6JTUJ616krefoT8/2X4A"><input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="XS-A316017C55EDE044A4AE01DDAD702D8D"><input type="hidden" name="Signature" value="hlTSFmQct5UllBmdgoUI3B2thBtMpXFWvP2e4NfbeWiS6c+tmBSzkRYwni4Z+D8kl7D+qnE980QQbjxM1yloIys2PI3xtoawzz5roC3d3UZkQKdXceykFMF0UB8XE74bWvg5c87cRewV7COEH3X94ggfYu1RNDoSOSNFsFKMSVs="><input type="hidden" name="SigAlg" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"><input id='targetUrl' name='targetUrl' type='hidden' value='https://accounts.sap.com'><input id='sourceUrl' name='sourceUrl' type='hidden' value=''><input id='org' name='org' type='hidden' value=''><input id='spId' name='spId' type='hidden' value='581d6aa0e4b01556e68e4b94'><input id='spName' name='spName' type='hidden' value='padevw3c34c012.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com'><input id='mobileSSOToken' name='mobileSSOToken' type='hidden' value=''><input id='tfaToken' name='tfaToken' type='hidden' value=''><input id='css' name='css' type='hidden' value=''><div class='ids-input-group ids-input-group--text ids-input-group--login ids-input-group--user' id='j_username-group'><div class='ids-label-container'><span class='ids-label-wrap'><label class='ids-label' for='j_username' id='j_username-label'>E-mail, ID, or User Name</label></span></div><div class='ids-control-container'><input autocomplete='off' class='ids-input ids-input--text ids-input--clear js-has-input-clear js-login-toggle-active-input-user' id='j_username' name='j_username' placeholder='E-mail, ID, or User Name' type='text' value='' /><p class='ids-error-block' id='j_username.errors'></p><a class='ids-input-clear js-input-clear' href='#' tabindex='-1'></a></div></div><div class='ids-input-group ids-input-group--text ids-input-group--login ids-input-group--password' id='j_password-group'><div class='ids-label-container'><span class='ids-label-wrap'><label class='ids-label' for='j_password' id='j_password-label'>Password</label></span></div><div class='ids-control-container'><input autocomplete='off' class='ids-input ids-input--text ids-input--clear js-has-input-clear js-login-toggle-active-input-password' id='j_password' maxlength='255' name='j_password' placeholder='Password' type='password' /><p class='ids-error-block' id='j_password.errors'></p><a class='ids-input-clear js-input-clear' href='#' tabindex='-1'></a></div></div><div class='ids-input-group ids-input-group--checkbox ids-utils-centered' id='rememberme-group'><div class='ids-control-container'><ul aria-labelledby='rememberme-label' class='ids-input-group__items' role='group'><li class='ids-input-group__item'><span class='ids-checkbox-container--option'><input id='rememberme' name='rememberme' type='checkbox' /></span><span class='ids-label-container--option'><span class='ids-label-wrap'><label class='ids-label' for='rememberme' id='rememberme-label'>Remember me</label></span></span></li></ul><p class='ids-error-block' id='rememberme.errors'></p></div></div></fieldset><div class='ids-button-group ids-button-group--centered ids-button-group--login'><button class='ids-button ids-button--primary ids-button--login js-button-login' id='logOnFormSubmit' role='button' type='submit'>Log On</button></div></form></div><ul class='ids-login-section'><li class='ids-login__forgotpassword'><a alt='Forgot password?' href='/ui/createForgottenPasswordMail?spId=581d6aa0e4b01556e68e4b94' id='forgotPasswordLink' title='Forgot password?'>Forgot password?</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></main><footer class='ids-footer'><div class='ids-footer__inner'><div class='ids-footer__logo-container'><div class='ids-footer__logo'><div id='test-default-logo'><img height="38" src="/universalui/assets/sap-ias-logo-powered-by-b5b87202d6d6cce7f87f332aac6a4764.svg" alt="Sap ias logo powered by" /></div></div></div></div></footer><script src="/universalui/assets/application-9be0c404ab371a30ab0c3b52f386217b.js"></script><script src="/universalui/assets/login-5e31c5876a96dbcadd5d83bce9c97cdc.js"></script><script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() {    var buttons = "#forgotPasswordLink, #forgotPasswordLinkMobile, #registerLink, #registerLinkMobile";    var addParamToButtons = function(paramName, paramValue) {        $(buttons).each( function() {            var link = $(this);            var url = link.attr("href");            var paramString;            if (url.indexOf('?') >= 0) {                paramString = "&";            } else {                paramString = "?";            }            paramString += paramName + "=" + encodeURIComponent(paramValue);            link.attr("href", url + paramString);        });    };    if ($.ids) {            var targetUrl = $.ids.overlay.getDestinationURI();        $("#targetUrl").attr("value", targetUrl);        addParamToButtons("targetUrl", targetUrl);        var sourceUrl = $.ids.overlay.getParentURI();        $("#sourceUrl").attr("value", sourceUrl);        addParamToButtons("sourceUrl", sourceUrl);    } else {    }});</script><script type='text/javascript'>function pageType() {  var pageType='Undefined';  var pageTypeFromPage = document.body.getAttribute('data-pagetype');  if (pageTypeFromPage != null) {    pageType = pageTypeFromPage;  }  return pageType;};function spName() {  var spName='Undefined';  var spNameFromPage = document.body.getAttribute('data-spname');  if (spNameFromPage != null) {    spName = spNameFromPage;  }  return spName;};function spId() {  var spId='Undefined';  var spIdFromPage = document.body.getAttribute('data-spid');  if (spIdFromPage != null) {    spId = spIdFromPage;  }  return spId;};var swa = {  pubToken: "1f27c1eb-778f-4cbe-83f5-e9aab5b7f148",  baseUrl: "https://trackerinta90daed17.hana.ondemand.com/tracker/",  visitorCookieTimeout: 63113852,  custom1:{ref:"pageType"},  custom2:{ref:"spName"},  custom3:{ref:"spId"}};(function(){  setTimeout(function () {    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script');    g.type="text/javascript";    g.async=true;    g.src=swa.baseUrl+"js/privacy.js";    document.body.appendChild(g);  }, 0);})();</script><script>  $.ids.overlay.isClickjackingProtectEnabled = true;</script></body>`